# Detecting barcode using android camera

Tags: java, android, android-camera, edge-detection

I am currently developing this Android phone application for the visually impaired people to detect and scan barcode. I am going to use ZXing(scanning via intent) for decoding barcode.

The problem now is, I need to use the camera to detect the presence of barcode around scanning region and alert the user via vibration or speech synthesizer. I am kind of stuck in this area now, I have tried borrowing books from the library and google searching for edge detection example, but to no avail:(

Can any kind soul please give me some advice in this area?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Answer (score 0):

There are other scanners on the market that use the full picture to detect barcodes. I know that [NeoReader](http://www.neoreader.com/) does not have this kind of *scanning region*.

It *may* be easier to find an API for different scanner then to detect barcodes (don't forget to focus...). Even *if* you find a way to detect codes, you still have to guide the visually impaired people to move the mobile so that the code will be inside the scanning area.